# how to redirect the site form add on site to main site using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect a add on site to main site uisng htaccess with www before the url.

actually my site is hosted in another domain as an add on.

suppose chaitanya.com is my site. abcd is the add on site in that domain

i installed wordpress in subfolder called "blog".

Now what i want is if any enter http://abcd.chaitanya.com/blog it will redirect to http://abcd.com/blog using htaccess

and i want to redirect the the wordpress installed in old site to the wordpress installed in new site that is
from oldsite.com/blog to newsite.com/blog.

Comment: This has to be done by your domain control panel, where it should say subdomain forwarding!

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Actually here abcd.com site is working.In google advance search it showing that link.now i want to redirect that links to main site using htaccess